# TaskHarness in React Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have a really serious problem. I created a Storybook under React. I am not getting the correct values on the Docs site as shown here.

[image]

Normally, it should give me something like:

[image]

and the values should be changed.

Here is my component file:

```
// Button/index.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Button as MButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import clsx from 'clsx';

export interface IButtonProps {}
const useStyles = makeStyles({});

const Button: React.FC<IButtonProps> = (props) => {
   return ();
};

export default Button;
```

And this one is my story file:

```
// index.stories.tsx
import { withPerformance } from 'storybook-addon-performance';

export default {
   decorators: [withPerformance],
} as Meta;
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Please, provide reproducible environment link.

Comment: I solved this problem by removing withPerformance from decorators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by removing withPerformance from decorators.

Edit:
Here is the solution:

```
import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/react';
import { withPerformance } from 'storybook-addon-performance';

addDecorator(withPerformance);
```

Comment: Can you explain what whas the problem and what `withPerformance` realy did to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @FilipSeman the problem was I could not get the values after changing them and it only was showing me TaskHarness thing.
After researching for it, I see that the withPerformance thing goes in front of the component. When I delete it, the problem solved. Will figure out how to add it later. It is important but seeing the values are my priority